# Expression tree - join 2 expressions with and

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I need to implement a method which makes and on 2 expression trees. Something like this:

```
public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> And(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> ex1, 
                                           Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> ex2)
{
    return Expression.And(ex1, ex2); 
}
```

In this case the return type is not what I need `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>`.
How to do what I need?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-optimal solution (untested):

```
public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> And(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> ex1, 
                                           Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> ex2)
{
  var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
  return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity,bool>>(
    Expression.And(
      Expression.Invoke(ex1, x),
      Expression.Invoke(ex2, x)), x); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> And(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> ex1, 
                                           Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> ex2)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(  
               Expression.And(
                   Expression.Invoke(ex1, parameter), 
                   Expression.Invoke(ex2, parameter)), 
           parameter); 
}
```

Note this won't work with Entity Framework unless you compact the Invokes. Google InvocationExpander for an implementation.

Comment: Will it work with NHibernate? It this function time-consuming?

Comment: @StuffHappens: The easier (and more portable) option would be to use: `query.Where(ex1).Where(ex2)`  :)

Comment: It's not scalable. I need also implement Or and Not (Specification pattern). And I wonder if the performance of Expression operations is suitable.

Comment: @StuffHappens: In that case. Extract the body of the Lambda, then use `ExpressionVisitor` to do parameter substitution.

Comment: Just Google InvocationExpander. It does that for you.